# Copy a row or column of a matrix and insert it in the next row/column

Tags: matlab, matrix, copy

I was wondering if there is an easy way in MATLAB to do the following operation: I'd like to copy a row or column of a matrix and insert it in the next row/column.

For example: given a 3x3 matrix

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I'd like to copy the first row and insert it as a second row:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Can someone advise how I could accomplish this in MATLAB? Thanks!

Comment: luckily it is matlab we are talking about, and matlab can do everything :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply repeat the indices of the rows you'd like to repeat

```
A = A([1 1 2 3],:)
```

Answer (score 3):

To insert row number `source` as row number `target`:

```
A = [A(1:target-1,:); A(source,:); A(target:end,:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [A(1,:); A];
```

Comment: Not general enough. The example the OP gave was using the first row, but his question was not. trutheality has the only general method which will work for any selection and insertion row.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old topic, but this post was coming up in searches I did for the same problem when I was looking for a specific Matlab function I couldn't remember the name of--padarray.

So, you could do:

A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];

A = padarray(A,[1 0],'replicate','pre');

This is often helpful if, for example, A is the output of a function that you have not saved explicitly, so you don't know what the first row is. Anyhow, hope this helps someone!