# Copying Two or More Rows from one matrix to another

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to reach and store 4 rows from a square matrix. Can you please help me? I have square matrix with size `10 x 10` and I am looking for rows number 2, 5, 6 and 9 to store them in one matrix.

Answer (score 3):

You can select the submatrix you want using this code:

```
B = A([2 5 6 9], :)
```

The `:` subscript will select all columns, which I am assuming is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6246982/3375713) and seems fairly easy. Try this

```
x = randi(10, 10);
x
y = x([2 5 6 9], :);
y
```

`y` then contains the rows 2, 5, 6, 9 from `x`. Hope that helps.